# Windbg PTE Null but memory is readable

Tags: windows, windbg

I am trying to understand PTEs on Windows with Windbg, for a stack address I get:

```
kd> dd 306F710
0306f710  00664db4 02f3fa3c 00000000 00000f04
0306f720  00664d78 00000000 00000000 00000000
0306f730  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0306f740  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0306f750  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0306f760  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0306f770  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0306f780  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
kd> !pte 306F710
                    VA 0306f710
PDE at C06000C0            PTE at C0018378
contains 0000000000000000
not valid
```

How can this work?

Comment: Did you try to follow the manual [steps described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/02/05/understanding-pte-part-1-let-s-get-physical.aspx)? What is the outcome? Where did it stop?

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: If you found a solution or could reproduce the output of `!pde`, could you describe it in an answer so that others can learn from it as well? Thank would be nice. Thanks.